# How to change a ul element to a div on the wp_nav_menu|

Tags: html, wordpress, wp-nav-menu-item

change the ul to a div

I need to change the ul tag to become a div.
I have changed the class from `sub-menu` to `nav__list-sub-alt nav__dropdown js-nav-next` using the code below

```
echo str_replace('sub-menu', 'nav__list-sub-alt nav__dropdown js-nav-next', wp_nav_menu( $defaults)
);
```

However I need to change the ul tag to a div tag

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with the <ul> element?

Answer (score 1):

you can change ul to whatever suits you, check out the documentation at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/ and look for **items_wrap**, default markup is `<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>` which can be replaced with anything.